# Is "Load" countable or non-countable?

Tags: articles, countability

Which one is correct:

> We notice that they may incur load to the box.

Or,

> We notice that they may incur a load to the box.

EDIT: the load means computing load.

Comment: What is being talked about? Electrical load in a junction box? A load of freight in a box car? More information is needed.

Comment: "Load" can be countable or non-countable, according to the context.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "load" here. Do you mean in the sense of cargo, like, "The longshoreman put a load of iron in the box"? Or something requiring electricity, like, "Replacing the 100 watt motor with a 200 watt motor significantly increased the load on the box"? Or some other kind of load?

Maybe regardless, the word "load" can be countable or uncountable. If you are talking about a specific load, than it is countable. "THE load on this circuit is 200 watts." If you are talking about the idea of (for example), electrical power requirements, then it is uncountable. "Our teacher explained the concept of load and how it affects electrical circuits."

I'm not sure what you're trying to say in your examples, but it sounds like you're talking about a specific load, in which case it would be countable. "We may incur A load."

Answer (score 0):

Load in a computing since is not normally experienced by a box but by a component which may be in the system box. You would normally say something like:

> This will increase load on the CPU.
> This will impose a load on the GPU.
> If load is maintained for too long the CPU may overheat and fail.
> If the load is maintained for too long the CPU may overheat and fail.
> If a load is maintained for too long the CPU may overheat and fail.

Interfaces may also experience a load as well of course those were just examples.

Comment: This doesn't address the question.  The phrasing "*the* load" doesn't distinguish between the countable and uncountable senses of the noun.  OP is interested in the difference between *to incur* ***a*** *load* and *to incur* ***[some]*** *load*.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan you are right, I have added some more examples of possible uses